# AntiforgeryValidationException when trying to login by two different tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

The steps: 
The login page is opened in two different tabs.

1. User A logs from Tab 1 (No issues)
2. Without refreshing the tab 2, user B tries to log in.
   Redirects to 400 page.

(Exception: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.)

Any solution to handle this?

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Are the tabs implemented by `Asp.Net Core view` or `Angular`? How did you configure `Antiforgery` in the tab? Did you place `Antiforgery` in the different tabs or the main page outside tabs? How did you configure `Antiforgery` in `Startup`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Asp.Net Core views. And I have '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()' in my Login View. '[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]' attribute have added to my login action in the controller. Sorry, I do not have a live demo to show you...

Comment: How did you achieve two tabs with login?

Comment: 1. Get to the login page
2. Duplicate the tab
(So now you have two tabs with login page)
3. From tab 1, user A logs in (No issues. login successful)
4. Now try login from tab 2 without refreshing it (by the same logged user or a different logged user.)
(*** Exception comes and redirects to 400 page)

Comment: Share us complete steps to reproduce your issue. By default, User A login will refresh the page, how did you avoid refreshing?

Comment: These are the steps: (And I'm referring to a chrome browser)
1. Open chrome. A new tab opened. Go to login page
2. Now right click on the tab and click on duplicate. (This will open a new tab with same url: which means now you have two login pages)
3. Now from tab 1 , User A logs in. (here no issue)
4. Now go to your duplicated tab : It has the login form and User B logs in from it. (Here comes the exception from 4th step)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with @matt-shepherd that this is the correct behavior of the anti-forgery token validation. Tab B is in an expired state because the token in Tab B does not reflect that we have already logged in in Tab A [the anti forgery token includes the username](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2#extend-antiforgery).

I am posting another answer here because in my app (.Net Core 2.2 using asp.net core identity and razor pages) `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate()` is not available.So I wasn't able to validate the token in the controller action as suggested by @matt-shepherd.

Instead I have created a filter inheriting from IAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilter thanks to [Patrick Westerhoff's pull request that was merged to ASP.NET Core 2.2 code base](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/8604) :

```cs
public class RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter : IAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilter
  {
    public Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
      if (context.Result is AntiforgeryValidationFailedResult)
      {
        context.Result = new RedirectToPageResult("/AntiForgeryError");
      }

      return next();
    }
  }
```

I have created a razor page named `AntiForgeryError`.

At last, I have configured my app to use the `RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter` in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add<RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter>())
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Comment: This is also a good answer for .NET Core 2.2, thanks @Yanal-Yves

Comment: I wanted to thank you so much for this answer. I ended up finding Patrick Westerhoff's PR first, but there are a lot of stale answers on this site for other questions for handling it as an exception which doesn't apply in Core 2.2+ world.

Comment: For those .net 8 and Program.cs, here's the updated syntax

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.Filters.Add<RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter>());

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct behaviour of the anti-forgery token validation. Tab B is essentially in an expired state. The only thing you can do here is to improve the way your system handles it.

I would recommend, for example, validating the token from *within* the controller action instead of using the attribute. To do this, just use this line as the first line of your Action: `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate();`. You can now catch any `HttpAntiForgeryException` thrown and respond to the user accordingly. e.g. telling the user that they're already logged in, or that they'll need to refresh the page, whichever is appropriate for your system.