# Is it safe to disable antiforgery token if samesite=strict on authentication cookie?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, samesite

According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2) ASP.NET core implements the Synchronizer Token Pattern to mitigate CSRF.

### The Anti request forgery mechanism has many drawbacks impacting users:

#### ex 1: login page opened in 2 tabs

- Open the login page in two different tabs
- User A logs from Tab 1 (No issues)
- Without refreshing the Tab 2, user B tries to log in.

=> Produces a 400 page with AntiforgeryValidationException

[reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760424/antiforgeryvalidationexception-when-trying-to-login-by-two-different-tabs/58284933#58284933),
[reference 2](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3616)

#### ex 2: a form opened in 2 tabs (from the same link in a mail)

- Create a new Asp.Net Core MVC website from template (VS 2019)
- Create a new page which has a simple form which is validated with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on post.
- Email yourself a link to that page (I've used Gmail & Mailtrap)
- Open the link in two tabs by clicking on it normally
- Submit both forms in any order

=> The form which was opened FIRST produces a 400 error

[reference](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13632)

### It looks like SameSite=strict is an effective security measure against CSRF attacks

According to this [article](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/same-site-cookie-attribute-prevent-cross-site-request-forgery/) and [this draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07#section-4.1.1), SameSite cookie seems an effective and robust security measure against CSRF attacks.
ASP.NET Core 2.2's authentication cookie are configured with SameSite=strict. If my understanding is correct, authentication cookie are only sent to the server in a same-site navigation situation.

In my use case I trust the sub domains.

So if I can guarantee that my users are using a browser supporting the SameSite policy, is it safe to disable the anti CSRF mechanism of my ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14251#issuecomment-544138663 makes me feel that it's safe to use samesite policy in a situation where I can guarantee that my user' browers supports SameSite policy.

Comment: Late comment, but FWIW: the answer to your question largely depends on how you define your attack surface. CSRF tokens and `SameSite` do not defend your users equally against all kinds of threats. In particular, `SameSite` is powerless against a cross-origin attack mounted from a subdomain of the target origin. Therefore, if you can't trust your subdomains, `SameSite` won't be enough to protect your users against cross-origin abuse. I've written about this elsewhere: b0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/

Comment: @jub0bs, thank you for your comment. I'm getting a 404 when trying to access the link you provided. Would you mind updating the link in your comment please ?

In my use case I trust the subdomain. I'll update my question to add this information.

Comment: Sorry, I only pasted the end of the link. Here is the correct one: https://jub0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413988/16462950