# Safe and unsafe HTTP methods relation to cross-site request forgery (CSRF)

Tags: http, csrf, endpoint

Sonar raises security alerts on backend endpoints allowing GET & POST methods, as described [here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3752).

How is it related to CSRF?

CSRF is explained by OWASP [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) but I don't get why having an endpoint opened in both GET & POST is harmful? If I limit it to a POST-only endpoint, the attacker can still build a CSRF POST request.

Comment: Sonar seems to assume that you have a framework in place that rejects all POST requests that lack a CSRF token, but does not reject GET requests. This is sufficient protection if side effects (for example, cancel a hotel booking) can be achieved only with POST requests (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413988/16462950)). But if the same effect could also be achieved with a GET request, that would be unprotected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Heiko said in comment, Sonar assumes we're using a framework that adds and handle CSRF Token for us on sensitive endpoints.

For example, Java Spring allows you to configure it as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html). Sonar assumes you've already configured it.

It's considering POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests but not considering GET requests because it assumes that your code follows the best practice: no data alteration in GET endpoints. Of course, you should adapt it to your use case, identifying what are your sensitive endpoints and configure it accordingly.